# HADR procedures

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, hadr

We are thinking of a SQL Server 2014 + Windows Server 2012 configuration for a HADR scenario. My questions are:

- on a HA scenario, how does the primary server get updated once it is again available ?
- on a DR scenario, how does the primary server get updated once it is again available ?

I am talking about WSFC + HADR not mirroring, Using Availability Groups.  Very much like this procedure
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/how-set-up-sql-server-denali-availability-groups/

Answer (score 0):

> on a HA scenario, how does the primary server get updated once it is again available ?

The primary server is always where the write workload goes. If you're asking how the replica gets updated once it transitions from Primary->Secondary the answer is it finds the primary and checks in with its' LSN. There is a negotiation that goes on and depending on what happens in the interim between down and connected to the new primary it may send log blocks until the old primary is caught up or it may require log backups to be applied or a complete new synchronization.

> on a DR scenario, how does the primary server get updated once it is again available ?

See the answer above. It works the same way.

Comment: ok, so if the primary (A) goes down, the secondary (B) becomes the new primary and when (A) gets up again, B will sync it.  I guess that when there is too much downtime for A, a complete new sync will have to be done.  Right ?

Comment: If A goes down and B becomes the new primary, then when A comes back up A syncs with B assuming both are synchronous replicas. If one is async then it can't auto failover and if the failover would be forced, A won't auto sync to B. If manually resumed, though, A would sync with B and potentially lose data.

Comment: thanks !  I just created 2 VMs to test this on the sync scenario.  Will test the async soon.